# Sql Server keep old references to deleted databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution with a DB named LearningDB.

Here is my connectionstring in my web.config

```
<add name="EntityFrameworkDbContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2008;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=LearningDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

My Sql Server is named SQL2008 and is a full SQL SERVER (not the express one).

**Strange thing:** when I run my solution, it successfully created the DB and allows me to add data to this DB. I didn't use the AttachDBFilename attribute (to specify where to store the DB) so the DB is located under C:\Users\Thierry\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQL2008

I already query the sys.databases to list my table but I only have 4 tables (master, tempdb, model, msdb). I would like to delete these corrupted references to deleted databases but I don't know where!

Any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT

As Mikael suggest me, I edit my question to be clear: I didn't want to delete master tables, etc...

Le'ts take an example: I have a DB named LearningDB.mdf in my asp.net mvc solution. I deleted physically this DB (with Windows Explorer, I know this is not the best thing to do). Next, when I restart my solution and run it, the system try to recreate the DB and warn me that the name LearningDB is already exist!! How this can be?? I already check in SQL SERVER with Management Studio but didn't found anything!